# HTTP 404 on commandButton navigation in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Consider a JSF page opened with the browser's address bar having the URL as `scheme://firstserver.group.com/proxy/secondserver.group.com/AppContext/pages/page1.faces`

Any operation performed on the same page works correctly, but when a navigation is done to page2.faces, the URL gets modified as `scheme://firstserver.group.com/AppContext/pages/page1.faces` and results in `HTTP 404`.

Sample code:

```
<h:form>
 <h:commandButton id="viewTransaction" action="#{bean.viewTransactionAction}" value="View Transaction"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>

String viewTransactionAction(){
  //do something
  return "page2"
}

<navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>page2</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/pages/page2.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
```

When I manually enter the URL `scheme://firstserver.group.com/proxy/secondserver.group.com/AppContext/pages/page2.faces` in the address bar, I am successfully able to navigate.

I tried to perform redirect using external context from bean method but that too resulted in `HTTP 404`.

How do I navigate to page2 without losing the prefixed URL?

Comment: Nothing seems wrong in your code. If you are using eclipse, use the debug mode and check where the problem is coming.

Comment: The environment in only available in UAT and Production and hence cannot debug.

Comment: the code seems fine to me...i mean nothing can go wrong here!

Comment: Yes, What we don't understand is why the part of the URL before context is lost.

Comment: So what I did was changed the form type from `<h:form>` to `<form action="/proxy/secondserver.group.com/AppContext/pages/page2.faces" method="post">` and set the request attributes in hidden fields using javascript. It worked perfectly.